# Through react-router-dom I want to call redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

According to a route change, I am looking for a better way to call the redux action. I can call a redux action trough render function. like below this way

```
render(){
  const filterName = this.props.match.params.product
  this.props.actions.filterProduct(filterName)
}
```

But I am looking for the best approach for a large application. Is there any way to bind redux action according to a route path?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to to this is to use `react-router-redux`. You will have actions dispatched that you can listen to in your reducers, e.g. when the route changes.

But actually I'm not sure if you need that in your case. If you just want to show products depending on the filter from the current route you can use `mapDispatchToProps` in your `connect()` method to filter them on demand. `mapDispatchToProps` get's passed the state and the original props of the component. You can grab the filter from there and filter the products from the store.

Also you should not dispatch an action on every render.

Comment: Yeah, you are right I can take props from the component and filter the product. But I am making an architect my plan is I will manage all those things thing trough redux action. Actually, I am looking for a central way to bind my redux action with the route changes. I think I need to go with react-route-redux.